# always data and ruby on rails hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, web-hosting

I want to use always data to host my ruby on rails web application but I need to upgrade from `ruby 1.9.2` to 2.1.2, and the same for `rails 3.2.11` to 4.1.8

Comment: Oh ya, go for it. What's your question though? (By the way, unless you're from the future, the Rails version should 4.1.8.)

Comment: my question is how to do this upgrade

Comment: Ok, well that type of question is way too broad for SO. There are many tutorials for upgrading from Rails 3.x to 4, which is likely the most problematic upgrade, and upgrading to ruby 2.x should be relatively simple, but again there are plenty of resources surrounding that. It's especially easy if you're using RVM. Any problems you encounter along the way are probably already answered in one of many SO posts. Just do some googling.